# Excel filters change if first filtered value does not exist

Tags: excel, filter, pivot, not-exists

**Pivot Filter Name**: Country_Flg, it takes 2 different value, these are 0,1. I am filtering my pivot as only **Counrty_Flg=1**.

Under some conditions, pivot table source updates and Country_Flg takes just 0 or 1. There is no problem when the value is only 1, but when the value is only 0, my filter changes and takes **Counrty_Flg=0**. My dashboard is feeding on this pivot tables. So, wrong values are showing on the dashboard. Besides, when **re-update** the pivot source, **it still remains 0**.

I couldn't find a way how I can anchor the value as 1 under all conditions.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r2fUS.png)

after source data updating, my filter value is changing because 1 doesn't exist anymore.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wGiLK.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/31KMS.png)

But I don't want to filter as 0. I need that if 1 doesn't exist, pivot should not bring any value.

Comment: Can you share images and/or data that would help to demonstrate this? Also, I am assuming Counrty_Flg is a typo.

Comment: Are you saying if the backing data changes and there are no 1s in it, your filter changes on update to 0 which does exist? If so, that is normal. You can't filter the field on a value that doesn't exist as the list comes from that data. You can use vba and a pivottable_update event to check if 1 exists and set the filter to that. But it is difficult to code a solution for every possible situation as depending on how your data is laid out and what other slicing elements are present will determine if 1 is an option for a valid filter (I think).

Comment: Are the pivottable fields fixed? I.e. you don't re-arrange how the pivots look?

Answer (score 1):

This is an example I was mentioning (given the constraints around pivottable layout remaining the same) where you can try to set to 1 otherwise you will have to default to 0 (if 1 does not exist). This goes in the code pane of the sheet associated with the pivot. I have used same spelling as you for the pagefield. Not ideal but best I could think of as you can't filter to a non-existent value. It will reset filter to 1 if it exists on refresh.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_PivotTableUpdate(ByVal Target As PivotTable)

    If Target.Name = "PivotTable1" Then          'change to your pivot name

        Application.EnableEvents = False

        Dim pvtField As PivotField

        Set pvtField = Target.PivotFields("Counrty_Flg")

        On Error GoTo DefaultValue

        With pvtField
            .ClearAllFilters
            .CurrentPage = "1"
        End With

        Application.EnableEvents = True

    End If

    Exit Sub

DefaultValue:

    If Err.Number <> 0 Then

        With pvtField
            .ClearAllFilters
            .CurrentPage = "0"
        End With

        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If

End Sub
```

Image:

[image: pivot]